# How To Write A While Loop To Prompt a Word & Exit The Loop of Another Word

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop

```
var i = window.prompt('Guess The Word')
while(i < 10);{
if(i < 10);
}
```

Please explain the concept of the while loop whether it's of numbers (i < 10) or words. I clearly don't understand the condition of loops. The only thing that comes up are If statements from google and those don't help

Comment: This code seem to be doing nothing but prompting. `if` condition is not inside `while loop` - notice the semicolon before `{`. Where did you take this code from?

Comment: W3 schools for while loop is that is what you are looking for: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp

Comment: i made the code assuming that if i apply the "if statement" then I would follow up with another condition for the code to make a decision

Comment: You are comparing a response (string) to a number the loop will never execute properly, javascript will try to convert it to something that is comparable then perform the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have semicolons after conditions for while or if statements, and you're missing a semicolon on the first line of code.

```
var i = window.prompt('Guess The Word');
while(i < 10){

}
```

Now, in the condition, you can check if the word is not correct.

```
var i = window.prompt('Guess The Word');
while(i != 'foo'){

}
```

If it is the word, in this case 'foo', then it will exit the loop and we can put a line of code after the loop which will execute in this case.

```
var i = window.prompt('Guess The Word');
while(i != 'foo'){

}
alert('Well done!');
```

If it is not the word, then you can prompt for the word again inside the loop. This prompt will keep executing until the condition becomes false (when i is infact equal to 'foo').

```
var i = window.prompt('Guess The Word');
while(i != 'foo'){
    var i = window.prompt('Guess The Word');
}
alert('Well done!');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Bro it helps a lot! I am si happy you taught me the concept. Even though you explained it, at first I still didn't understand until I thought REALLY hard about it and visualized that on my mind. And it finally clicked! I didn't understand the part where the i != 'foo' cause i was like the word has to be that. It was when you said if the word is 'foo' the loop would automatically exit and execute another line of code that assures it's the word. Thanks again